# Double click on WPF shape event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, shapes

I am trying to capture an event after an Ellipse on my WPF form has been double clicked. I am not sure what is the best practice to do so, since the WPF System.Windows.Shapes does not contain a double click event.

I have tried capturing a normal mouse button down with the click count as 2.

```
    private void SetupProjectsCOEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //If double clicked
        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            PopupEntityDetails(this, ProjectsContext, LocalUser, TreeSetup.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get what I want by using a ContentControl:

```
<ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="Ellipse_DoubleClick">
    <Ellipse Name="SetupProjectsCOEllipse" Width="10" Height="10"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

`MouseDown` should work fine, if it isn't then a parent somewhere in the visual is preventing he bubbling event from tunneling back down again. This also explains why wrapping the shape in a `ContentControl` "fixes" it.

Next time use `PreviewMouseDown` instead. That's the bubbling event, so you'll have a chance to catch it before it gets intercepted.

Comment: I've tried the `PreviewMouseDown` with `if (e.ClickCount >= 2)` and it works for me. I did not need to use `ContentControl` (Which would have been a hassle in my case). Thanks for the help :D.